# How to use a file read via "FileHandler" of "FileAccess API" inside "img" tag

Tags: image, base64, file-system-access-api

Here's a detailed explanation on what I'm trying to do-

I'm reading a HTML file from a directory which has the image tag used but the assets are mapped locally and are not from url.

So somehow I'm able to get access to the file.

`const fileHandle = await dirHandler.getFileHandle(file);`

Now, I somehow want to use the content of this file inside img tag.

The way it's possible is using having a base64 url encoded file.

I'm not finding much stuff/detail on this.

A help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a base64 data url nor do you want it, instead [create a blob: URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) from the File object your FileHandle points to. To retrieve this File object, call the [`getFile()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemFileHandle/getFile) method of your handle.

```js
const file = await fileHandle.getFile();
const url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
img.src = url;
```

or in a single line

```js
img.src = URL.createObjectURL(await fileHandle.getFile());
```

Comment: Thanks to you now I get the url which comes out to be something like this: 
http://localhost:3000/e3ee1204-f1c4-4905-bb21-1fd12a450199

But when I try to open this "url" it gives 404

Is it suppose to behave this way?

Comment: You should have `blob:` in front of this URL, so something like `blob:http://localhost:3000/e3ee1204-f1c4-4905-bb21-1fd12a450199`

Comment: Yeah! Thanks buddy ;)
I can see that image now.